# Python module win32com on Linux

Tags: python, python-import, multiplatform

I am writing some Python code that runs under multiple platforms. Unfortunately under Win32, I have to support some COM functionalities.

However these lines will fail under an Linux environment:

```
from pythoncom import PumpWaitingMessages
from pythoncom import Empty
from pythoncom import Missing
from pythoncom import com_error
import win32api
```

And all the other functions which are using the Win32 COM API will fail as well. What is the standard method to make sure that some code is not loaded/imported depending on the platform and give an error message/exception in the case they are called by the client of the interface ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`try..except ImportError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ImportError):

```
try:
    from pythoncom import PumpWaitingMessages
    from pythoncom import Empty
    from pythoncom import Missing
    from pythoncom import com_error
    import win32api
except ImportError:
    # handle exception
```

What to do when there is an exception is up to you. You could add Linux-specific code that provides an analogous interface, or you could use the [`warnings` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) to tell the user that certain functions/features are unavailable.

---

Alternatively, you could use an `if-statement` based on the value of `sys.platform`:

```
import sys
if sys.platform == "win32":
    ...
elif sys.platform == 'cygwin':
    ...
elif sys.platform[:5] == 'linux':
    ...
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Other values which may be important for cross-platform code may be [os.name](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.name) (which could equal `'posix'`, `'nt'`, `'os2'`, `'ce'`, `'java'`, `'riscos'`), or [platform.architecture](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.architecture) (which could equal things like `('32bit', 'ELF')`.)

Comment: This solves the import, but the functions which are using the imports will still fail, isn't it ?

Comment: The functions that are Windows-specific should be placed inside the `try-suite`. Analogous functions that are Linux-specific should be placed in the `except-suite`.

Comment: Thanks, that is great, I am gonna try this asap.