# Is win32com library available on Linux?

Tags: linux, win32com

I want to use win32com.client module on Linux.
So is there any problem to use it?

Comment: Possible  [duplicate:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927131/python-module-win32com-on-linux)

Answer (score 6):

> Is win32com library available on Linux?

## Certainly not.

[win32com](https://superuser.com/q/609447/107016) looks like a *Windows specific* library, tied to the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

Linux has a different [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) API (because Linux is not Windows and both are *different* OSes), mostly following the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standards. For example, both Linux and Windows have [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file), [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)), [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading), [users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_(computing)), etc... but the details about them vary greatly and significantly (and you need to understand them, since "[the evil is in the details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_devil_is_in_the_detail)");

To learn the Linux operating system API, read a good Linux programming book. The [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) book is freely downloadable, even if it is a bit old (but most of its content still apply); and you could get (e.g. buy) newer books.

For more, read the [`man` pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) (which are the canonical documentation on Unix). In particular [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and the many other pages refereed from it. You'll also need to look into the [section 3](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_3.html) of `man` pages, since it is listing *many* functions usable in Linux.

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/)

You might find (but this is programming language specific) some framework libraries trying to provide some common abstractions above several OSes. Look (for C++) into [Qt](https://qt.io/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [Boost](https://boost.org/), etc....

At last, don't forget that Linux is made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). Sometimes, it is useful to download them and study their source code. In some occasions, that is a good approach to [leaky abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).

PS. **Budget several *weeks* of your time to read documentation and books**, and perhaps study the source code of some free software similar to your goals.